# "Unable to create directory "/Debug/". Access to the path "/Debug/" is denied." when opening Unity3D project with Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, msbuild

I moved to Ubuntu 19.04 from Windows 10, and I have some Unity projects from the past to work on. I installed VS Code from the Microsoft site, the C# and Unity Debugger extensions, .NET SDK 2.2, latest Mono (6.0.0.319) and Unity 2019.2.0f1. When I try to open the project, the OmniSharp log says:
`[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader Unable to create directory "/Debug/". Access to the path "/Debug/" is denied.`
and some other errors led by this, which cause the .csproj file not to load.

First, I've googled the problem, but found only one suiting thread saying I need to reinstall `msbuild`. But there isn't any `msbuild` package on APT, so I went to MSBuild's GitHub and it said `msbuild` wasn't shipping separately from .NET SDK.
Then I uninstalled Mono, but VSC said me I don't have the ".NET Framework 4.7.1", so I installed Mono again.
Later I reinstalled both .NET SDK and VS Code, but the issue seemed to remain.

This is my `dotnet --info` if it can help solving:

```
Пакет SDK для .NET Core (отражающий любой global.json):
 Version:   2.2.401
 Commit:    729b316c13

Среда выполнения:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  19.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.19.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.2.401/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.6
  Commit:  7dac9b1b51

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.401 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

The OmniSharp log itself (starting from the warn):

```
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/home/alt3r3d/UnityProjects/some random test' on host 14700.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        Unable to create directory "/Debug/". Access to the path "/Debug/" is denied.
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        Could not write state file "/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.csprojAssemblyReference.cache". Could not find a part of the path "/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.csprojAssemblyReference.cache".
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader
        Could not write lines to file "/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache". Could not find a part of the path "/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache".
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/home/alt3r3d/UnityProjects/some random test/Assembly-CSharp.csproj'.
/home/alt3r3d/UnityProjects/some random test/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
/home/alt3r3d/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.0/.omnisharp/1.34.0/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1144,5): Error: Unable to create directory "/Debug/". Access to the path "/Debug/" is denied.
/home/alt3r3d/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.0/.omnisharp/1.34.0/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2130,5): Error: Could not write state file "/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.csprojAssemblyReference.cache". Could not find a part of the path "/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.csprojAssemblyReference.cache".
/home/alt3r3d/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.0/.omnisharp/1.34.0/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3450,5): Error: Could not write lines to file "/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache". Could not find a part of the path "/Debug/Assembly-CSharp.csproj.CoreCompileInputs.cache".

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /home/alt3r3d/UnityProjects/some random test/Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

Comment: Did you try it: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/msbuild-stable/ ?

Comment: I have tried it now, this doesn't seem to help. The issue still remains.

Comment: @alt3r3d I'm not on Ubuntu, but in my case installing the `msbuild-stable` package from the AUR as suggested above did not work, since it was an out-of-date version. I had to edit the PKGBUILD and install the newest one, 16.4, which worked.